# Inductive proof that $64 \mid 7^{2n} + 16n - 1$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Let us suppose that $P(n)$ be the statement –

$P(n)$: $7^{2n} + 16n - 1$ is divisible by $64$  or $P(n)$: $64$ | $7^{2n} + 16n - 1$

- Base Case:

We check if $P(n)$ holds true for $n = 1$. $P(1):$

$7^{2.1} + 16.1 - 1= 64$. As we know, $64$ divides $64$. Hence, $P(1)$ is true.

- Inductive Step:

Let us assume that $P(n)$ holds true for some arbitrary integer $k$ such that $k > 0$. In other words, we have $P(k)$ is true. Now, according to this step, we must prove that $P(k+1)$ holds true as well.

We have $P(k)$ is true, or $64$ | $7^{2k} + 16k - 1$

Hence, we can infer that $7^{2k} + 16k - 1$ is a factor of $64$ and write that $7^{2k} + 16k - 1 = 64m$ where $m$ is some integer such that $m > 0$

And we have to show that $64$ | $7^{2(k+1)} + 16(k+1) - 1$

- Proof:

We have $P(k+1)$

= $7^{2(k+1)} + 16(k+1) - 1$

=$49.7^{2k} + 16(k+1) - 1$

Since k is an integer, so in $16k - 1$ and so is $49(16k - 1)$. Hence, adding and subtracting $49(16k - 1)$, we have

P(k + 1) = $49.7^{2k} + 16(k+1) - 1 + 49(16k - 1) - 49(16k - 1)$

= $49.7^{2k} + 16(k+1) - 1 + 49.16k - 49 - 49.16k + 49$

= $49(7^{2k} + 16k - 1) + 16.48k + 64$

= $49.64m + 12.64k + 64$

= $64(49m + 12k + 1)$

= $64p$ where p is some integer equal to $49m + 12k + 1$. This is because, since m and k are integers, so is  $49m + 12k + 1$.

Hence, we have proved that that $P(k + 1)$ is a factor of 64 or in other words, $64$ divides
$7^{2(k+1)} + 16(k+1) - 1$.

So by the step of Inductive hypothesis, we have showed that if $P(n)$ holds true for some arbitrary integer $k$, it holds true for $k+1$ as well. This completes our proof by Induction.

> Is this correct?

Comment: There are som $n$'s which should be $k$'s after your "We have $P(k)$ is true". Also, replace your title by a shorter but more informative one, like "Inductive proof that $64\mid7^{2n}+16n-1$". And don't write "$P(1)=$ some number" ($P(1)$ is an assertion, not a number).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by “research proof?”

Comment: @templatetypedef noting much, just a short assignment for one of my classes

Comment: @AnneBauval appreciate it thanks

Comment: Don't say $P(k+1) = ......$.  $P(k+1)$ is a statement about $k+1$.  If you want a number to serve as notation for $7^{2k} + 16k -1$, introduce one.  Say let $A(n) = 7^{2n} + 16n -1$.  THe your $P(k)$ *statement* is $P(k) =$" $A(n)$ is divisible by $64$.... Otherwise....Eyeballing your proof looks correct and how I'd do it.  But I didn't actually check that your arithmetic actually works though.  If it does you proof is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Much of your work can be simplified by defining $f(n) = 7^{2n} + 16n - 1$ and then noting that if the statement $$64 \mid f(k)$$ is true, then $$f(k+1) - 49 f(k) = 16(k+1) - 1 - 49(16k - 1) = -64(12k-1);$$ that is to say, $$f(k+1) = 49f(k) - 64(12k-1),$$ so $64 \mid f(k+1)$ and by the induction hypothesis, $f(n)$ is divisible by $64$ for all positive integers $n$.